# How much is too much restriction?

Tags: php, error-handling, user-input, validation

I have a function that sets what key a song is in for a search query. It goes from `c..b` or `0..11` and I have it to where if the given "key" falls outside the allowed range, it just reverts to `NULL`. Should I be throwing an Exception instead warning that the supplied $key is outside of the allowed range?

Here is the code:

```
<?php
function between($x, $y, $z) {
    return (($x <= $y) && ($y <= $z));
}

function setKey($key) {
    if (is_string($key)) {
        $key = array_search(strtolower($key), array("c", "c-sharp", "d", "e-flat", "e", "f", "f-sharp", "g", "a-flat", "a", "b-flat", "b"));
    } else {
        $key = (!between(0, $key, 11)) ? false : $key;
    }
    return (!$key) ? null : $key;
}

var_dump(setKey("g"))."\n";
var_dump(setKey("r"))."\n";
var_dump(setKey(2))."\n";
var_dump(setKey(12))."\n";
```

Output:

```
int(7)
NULL
int(2)
NULL
```

Comment: How about posting the function here instead of linking off-site?

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate concerns here.

The first is validating the input is within an allowed range and supplying feedback to the user if they enter a value outside the range. You should definitely perform this validation. Where possible, make these values obvious to the user before they start typing, or present the selection in a way that removes the likelihood of error.

The second concern is whether an exception should be thrown. Ideally, exceptions should only be raised in this fashion when your program cannot execute given the current state, or continuing could result in data corruption. I don't think this is the case in your scenario as you are simply performing a read.

For your specific scenario, I would use validation, but not exceptions. I have included the additional detail so people with subtly different scenarios can make an informed decision when they come across the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's always a good idea to let the user know their input was out of range. It's most likely a typo that the user would be happy to know about and correct.